# Media query workaround for IE is messing the whole thing

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

```
<![if lt IE 9]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="cssfiles/1024.css" />
<![endif]>

<link rel="stylesheet" media="(min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 1024px)" href="cssfiles/1024.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="(min-width: 1025px)and (max-width: 1366px)" href="cssfiles/1366.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="(min-width: 1367px)" href="cssfiles/1367.css" />
```

without the IE workaround the queries work fine. But when I add that IE works fine but chrome (I only tested in chrome) when I resize the browser, the 1024 and 1366 query work fine but 1367 is getting replaced by 1024.

Please help me

Comment: Consider using `respond.js` for full media queries support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the part of the conditional comment that makes it a comment to the browser.

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="cssfiles/1024.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Add the dashes to let browser's know that that snippet is a comment not to be rendered. Internet Explorer will pick it up from there and render the comment if it is applicable. Currently, it's not formatted like a comment so all the browser's are trying to parse it resulting in invalid HTML markup.

**Reference:** [Conditional Comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html)